# Use method(having variables of form this.variable) of class in the body of another class in js

Tags: javascript

I have a class Hotspot which has a method and one of its method uses class variable `this.pano_id`.
The class is like this

```
function Hotspot(pano_id){
    alert("First: " + pano_id);
    this.pano_id = pano_id;
}
```

and it has method

```
Hotspot.prototype.Hotspots = function (){
    alert(this.pano_id);
};
```

Now I have created an instance of class in some other file like this

```
var hotspot = new Hotspot(pano_id);
TweenLite.to(clear_pano[pano_num].material.materials[i], time, {opacity: 1, ease: Expo.easeOut, onComplete: hotspot.Hotspots});
```

It is making the class object and then calling the method Hostpots and in that I have used `this.pano_id`, but this doesn't seem to work as it alerts undefined. I tried printing `this` on console and it is the class object of the TweenLite object.
Is there a way by which I can use this.pano_id?

Comment: Try `onComplete: hotspot.Hotspots.bind(hotspot)`. Also, name your method camelCase. PascalCase is a convention for constructors only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't work because `hotspot.Hotspots` is invoked in different context (`TweenLite` object). Wrap it into anonymous function and call `hotspot.Hotspots` explicitly:

```
var hotspot = new Hotspot(pano_id);
TweenLite.to(clear_pano[pano_num].material.materials[i], time, {
    opacity: 1,
    ease: Expo.easeOut,
    onComplete: function() {
        hotspot.Hotspots();
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution gives an error `TypeError: hotspot.Hotspots is not a function`

Comment: It's not possible, that `hotspot.Hotspots()` throw `TypeError` but `hotspot.Hotspots.bind(hotspot)` works. But whatever glad you resolved it.